# Avoid duplication in multiple fields in SQL

Tags: php, sql

```
id  user_id     friend_id

 134       1            2
 132       2            1
  82       1            5
  48       1            4
  28       4            1
  10       6            1
```

I have a table of which includes above details. From this, I need only one row which not duplicate two fields(`user_id`, `friend_id`).i.e in first row there is `user_id = 1` and `friend_id = 2`,and in second row `user_id = 2` and `friend_id = 1`. I don't need to have both rows with same values.

Is it possible to write a query for the following output?

```
id  user_id     friend_id

 134       1            2
  82       1            5
  48       1            4
  28       4            1
  10       6            1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to return a row if the switched friendship doesn't exist - for a higher id (to keep one of the pairs.)

```
select t1.*
from tablename t1
where not exists (select * from tablename t2
                  where t1.user_id = t2.friend_id
                    and t1.friend_id = t1.user_id
                    and t2.id > t1.id)
```

And here's an alternative version, influenced by scaisEdge (thanks!):

```
select * from your_table 
where (user_id, friend_id) not in (select friend_id, user_id from your_table)
   or user_id > friend_id
order by id desc;
```

The `or user_id > friend_id` is there to keep one instance of each pair.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a `GROUP BY` query, and `greatest` and `least` functions:

```
select
  max(id) AS id,
  least(user_id, friend_id) as user_id,
  greatest(user_id, friend_id) as friend_id
from
  tablename
group by
  least(user_id, friend_id) as user_id,
  greatest(user_id, friend_id) as friend_id
```